# Update having "fromlist"

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, sybase

I have a sql update query as follows:

```
update #tree c 
set treetop=p.treetop,
treeptag=p.treeptag,
adjust= 'a2a'
from #tree p ,#regions r 
where c.treeptag=''
and   c.xsreg=r.Region
and    c.xsreg <> c.reg
and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')
```

I am trying to write a query without using the "fromlist" using joins as follows:

```
update #tree c 
set treetop=(select p.treetop from #tree p ,#regions r 
                      where c.treeptag=''
                      and   c.xsreg=r.Region
                      and    c.xsreg <> c.reg
                      and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
              and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')),
treeptag=(select p.treeptag from #tree p ,#regions r 
                      where c.treeptag=''
                      and   c.xsreg=r.Region
                      and    c.xsreg <> c.reg
                      and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
              and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')),
adjust= 'a2a'
where exists (select 1 from #tree p ,#regions r  where c.treeptag=''
and   c.xsreg=r.Region
and   c.xsreg <> c.reg
and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ',''))
```

However the above query seems to return incorrect number of rows; Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is correct, so the number of rows should be exactly the same. If the tables are small, update the question with the DDL and sample data inserts. Otherwise, what do these return?

```
select count(1)
from #tree c, #tree p ,#regions r 
where c.treeptag=''
and   c.xsreg=r.Region
and    c.xsreg <> c.reg
and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')
```

and

```
select count(disctint c.id)  -- or whatever the unique key on #tree is
from #tree c, #tree p ,#regions r 
where c.treeptag=''
and   c.xsreg=r.Region
and    c.xsreg <> c.reg
and c.tradedate=p.tradedate
and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')
```

and how do both counts compare to the update?  I would have thought it will match the 2nd count.

For what it's worth, it's 2012, so use proper ANSI joins:

```
update c 
   set treetop=p.treetop, treeptag=p.treeptag, adjust='a2a'
  from #tree c
  join #tree p on c.tradedate=p.tradedate
  join #regions r on c.xsreg=r.Region 
 where c.treeptag='' and c.xsreg <> c.reg
   and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')
```

And some of your conditions are directly against `c`, so why involve them in the subqueries?

```
update #tree c
   set treetop =(select p.treetop
                   from #tree p
                   join #regions r on c.xsreg=r.Region
                  where c.tradedate=p.tradedate
                    and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')),
       treeptag=(select p.treeptag
                   from #tree p
                   join #regions r on c.xsreg=r.Region 
                  where c.tradedate=p.tradedate
                    and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ','')),
       adjust  ='a2a'
 where c.treeptag='' and c.xsreg <> c.reg and -- << these two
exists (select 1
          from #tree p
          join #regions r on c.xsreg=r.Region
         where c.tradedate=p.tradedate
           and p.treeaotag=replace(r.srvid+':'+c.tradedate+':'+c.litag,'  ',''))
```